# Append to parent

Tags: html, jquery

I have this HTML structure:

```
<ul class="shopp_categories">
    <li><a href="#">TEXT</a>
        <ul class="children">
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
</ul>
```

And this my JS:

```
jQuery('.shopp_categories ul.children').parent().append('###');
```

My function does not append the content correctly. It shall look like:

```
<ul class="shopp_categories">
    <li>->####<-<a href="#">TEXT</a>
        <ul class="children">
            <li><a href="#">TEXT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
</ul>
```

Without the arrows, of course, after my function was executed. Where is the error in my code?

Comment: It looks correct. The first parent of UL is LI. What- in your mind - should be the correct location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$(function(){
    $('.shopp_categories li').find('ul').parent().prepend('###');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xkeshav/UknL3/3/)**

Answer (score 5):

Your javascript is wrong.

Try that:

```
$(function(){
    $('.shopp_categories li:first').prepend('###');
});
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/UknL3/

Comment: What, if I have more than one children list?

Comment: Should use "prepend" instead of "append". Also i changed the selector little bit to make it easy.

Answer (score 2):

Append will put it at the *end*.  Prepend will put it at the *beginning*.  Try using `prepend('###');` instead.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is invalid, to be sure, but why not use [an index selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)?

```
$(".shopp_categories li:eq(0)").prepend("###");
```

This way you can easily alter the index of the item you're intending to change. Simply change the value within parenthesis of `eq`, e.g. `eq(x)`.